# Mobile Compatibility: traditional website look vs native application ?

Tags: web-development, design, mobile

I have a question related to mobile compatible websites, I have seen two type of websites

One in which they adopt traditional website look and adjust website according to mobile screen, if they have lot of information which can not be adjust according to screen then they expand the height of page, so that user can scroll the page to see more information...

In the second approach they used native application look means use navigation-bar, tab-bar, tool-bar, scroll-view just like in native applications. Height and width of page adjust according to screen size, if they have more information then they use scroll-view etc...

My question is: which approach is better then other, in which approach you feel more comfortable to use website.

Comment: This might be better suited for the [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange. But alas, I lack the reputation to be allowed to vote for a move.

Comment: @BenjaminKloster, thanks for the information, I didn't know about "User Experience". I'll use your suggested website next time.

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

Comment: @BenjaminKloster you don't vote for a move to anything but meta and stackoverflow, you `flag` using `other` and let the moderator know what you think needs to be done.

Comment: It's a bit too open-ended a question for ux.se really. Now, if you have a specific use-case (i.e. is a mobile website or an app more appropriate *for a popular banking site*) then that'd fit in more with ux.se. Currently the only real answer here *'Well it depends on what the purpose / audience of the app/site is'*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the recent trend in mobile development, it is better to make the mobile website  look and feel as the traditional one. There is no need to create a native app if mobile site does not use video/audio intensively.

Of course, mobile website will display only main body/part of the traditional website, while hiding left/right and all additional sections, due to the screen width limitations. In this way, support and maintainability of each(mobile/web) sites will be more manageable with less resources in long run.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about mobile sites and mobile applications, then  here interesting research [Mobile Sites vs. Apps: The Coming Strategy Shift](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/mobile-sites-apps.html). In short, Jakob Nielsen recommend to build Mobile application if you have a budget for it, but he predict, that in future mobile version of site will be more preferable solution.

Basanta Tandon in presentaion: [Mobile Site vs. Apps – Comparison and Best Practices](http://www.usabilitysciences.com/assets/pdf/Usability_Sciences_Mobile_Sites_vs_Apps_Sept2010.pdf) propose a little bit another view on this problem.
He propose to build native application in following cases:

- 2-10% of your visitors are coming via the mobile devices
- There’s a need for built-in hardware features
- Focused marketing in an App store

In my opinion, it's good to build mobile application for website. But It should be as an additional features, not just to provide another way to access website information. Mobile application can really different usability and application developers should use this to improve loyalty of audience.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) is an attempt to provide a boilerplate to help you answer that in one website smoothly. Great concept, but if you already have the site designed, it can be absurd to try and implement.

I tried doing that for mine and gave up after a week...